# How to add text to the user registration form?

Tags: users

I've been using the [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module to change a few of the text fields in the `user/register` form. I've found this approach to be simple and effective.

However, I want to insert some text below the "User Account" heading but above the "Email" field. Just some general information about signing up. Unfortunately there is no text there currently so I can't use "String Overrides". Is there a simple way of adding some text? I don't want to create an entire custom registration form and reinvent the wheel, I just want to add some text to the existing form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to write your own custom module, you can use the [Field Group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group) module.  Enable the module and on the `Manage fields` tab for users, add a `Fieldset` and then set the description to whatever text/HTML you like.  Afterwards, just drag it to the place you want it to appear.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`hook_form_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) like this.

```
  function MODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    switch($form_id) {  
      case 'user_register_form': // the value we stole from the rendered form  
        $form['cutomtext'] = array(
        '#type' => 'item',
        '#markup' => '<div > Your text goes here... </div>',
        '#weight' => 1, // Adjust so that you can place it whereever 
        );
        break;  
    }  
  }
```

[Form API Reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7)

Also you could try [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)

Usage :

```
function hook_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Modification for the form with the given form ID goes here. For example, if
  // FORM_ID is "user_register_form" this code would run only on the user
  // registration form.

  // Add a checkbox to registration form about agreeing to terms of use.
  $form['terms_of_use'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t("I agree with the website's terms and conditions."),
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
}
```

Comment: To do this, I have to create my own module yes?

Comment: @Clinton Yes of course.

Comment: I think hook_form_FORM_id_alter() is more appropriate in this case.

Comment: @Xio, yes `hook_form_FORM_id_alter` is better when it comes to performance.

Answer (score 2):

'#type' => 'item' won't use attribute #value, it should be changed to #markup

```
function MODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    switch($form_id) {  
      case 'user_register_form': // the value we stole from the rendered form  
        $form['cutomtext'] = array(
        '#type' => 'item',
        '#markup' => '<div > Your text goes here... </div>',
        '#weight' => 1, // Adjust so that you can place it whereever 
        );
        break;  
    }  
  }
```

You can also place it in your theme's template.php file. In this case the first line changes to function THEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){...

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a bit late for the OP as he has another solution, but for anyone finding this page from Google, a much simpler way is to create a new block with the required text in and just set it to appear at the top of the main section or in a side bar.  This does not get it in between the username and email address, but requires less coding to implement